# How to make load balancing sticky for multiple clients in a same "group"?

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, nginx

The group can be determined by something like a cookie `group-id=123` (set client-side). Can this be done between several servers by Azure services? And what about several processes in a single server (using NodeJS)?

We are facing the needs of scaling socket.io application, the program is half state-less and should be able to handle these situations. It would be much complexer if we need to keep the data integrity and the program fully state-less the same time.

Comment: Please refine your question. Include sample deployment scenario, steps that you tried but didn't work, what didn't work and steps to reproduce. Otherwise your question will be considered off-topic as Too Broad.

Comment: The question is quite specific imho (regular sticky session is targeting separate clients, but I wish the clients in the same group will always connect to the same server, same process), and we are open to different services if they could be the solutions.

Comment: just that you don't really place a sample configuration. You can run NodeJS application in 3 Azure Services - Azure VM, Azure Cloud Service - Worker Role and Azure Web Apps. And you can run NGINX in two of them  - Azure VM and Azure Cloud Service Worker Role. So, first you have no idea how to run your service and what specific Azure Services to use, but you ask for a solution ....

Comment: just a note - using sticky session in a Cloud service is generally bad idea (whatever the cloud service may be - from Azure, through Amazon to whatever other public cloud). Because all cloud vendors require from you to have your servers deployed in Availability Sets/Groups or whatever they name it, to give you a SLA. Because, a single server can be restarted/re-imaged at any point in time with or without warning. And such things happen in public cloud. And not only that. Using sticky sessions you heavily dis-load-balance your traffic...

Comment: We are not actually using Azure for now at all, and we are not familiar with Azure. Any possible solution could be accepted. I am asking whether it could be done by Azure so that we can decide whether we should spend more time on that.

Comment: Thanks for the note, though. We are facing the needs of scaling socket.io application, the program is half state-less and should be able to handle these situations. It would be much complexer if we need to keep the data integrity and the program fully state-less the same time.

Comment: Check out this brief description for Azure LB: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-overview/
now that you briefly/widely described your issue, I don't believe you can fully achieve your goal without any hack things, which require deep understanding how Azure works + some additional Microsoft Services like ARR for IIS: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2013/09/19/advanced-cookie-based-session-affinity-with-application-request-routing.aspx  http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/10/31/application-request-routing-in-csf/

Comment: Thanks a lot, will take a closer look~ ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Nginx *ip_hash* but you can figure out which upstream server to use based on cookies and map function, see details: http://syshero.org/post/123124082042/persistent-backend-selection-using-cookies-with

The code example:

```
cookie_beid $backend {
  default www.globo.com:80;
  1       www.uol.com.br:80;
  2       www.ig.com.br:80;
  3       www.terra.com.br:80;
}

server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name _;

  resolver 4.2.2.2;

  location ~ ^/app(?<beid>[0-9]+) {
    add_header Set-Cookie   "beid=${beid};Max-Age=31536000";
    return 301 /;
  }

  location / {
    add_header X-Backend $backend;
    add_header X-BeID $cookie_beid;
    proxy_pass http://$backend;
  }

}
```

To perform more controlled upstream selection you can allow backend to set the cookie instead.

Comment: Appreciate your answer on the NGINX part, however when you run services in Azure there is always the Azure Load Balancer before your servers. Upon which, depending on the service you chose, you have less or more control.

Comment: Could you try to have a gateway infront of your servers where it handles the routing?